# Converting float to int not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pulling numbers from a sheet and comparing them from user selection via html. However even though the numbers in the google sheet are all int type numbers such as 1001, 1002 et cetera the numbers in Logger.log show up as floats. When trying to compare the numbers against the user input always comes up as false comparing a float (from sheet) to int (from user).

I've tried converting the returned float to an int using parsteInt, Math.floor and round. It doesnt seem to convert the variable. Is there another method I should be using?

Comment: It works for me. Can you please share your code and output of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I get this kind of issue and use 2 workarounds :
For a script I have to store a value in a property but when I call property it is a text and not number, double number was not an issue for my calculation. So I do :

```
var prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var number = parseInt(prop.getProperty('PROPERTY_NAME'));
//do some stuffs after
```

Fo another script I had to be a little bit more dirty, because from the property I get for example "8.0" instead of "8". So i do :

```
var prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var value = prop.getProperty('PROPERTY_NAME');
var number = number.split(".")[0];
```

At the end it works.

Stéphane

Comment: I believe `number.split...` in the example should be `value.split...`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have ints or floats... just numbers. So 3.0 and 3 are equal, if they are numbers.

Chances are that your user input is a string, not a number. You'll need to coerce the string to a number.

```
if (+userInput === 3) { etc.
```

There are [lots more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+coerce+number+is%3Aquestion) of this in other questions.